# Upload file into S3 bucket with correct format

Tags: fileupload

I had uploaded a .txt file to AWS S3 bucket.
on opening file, it showed data like

> > `aHR0cHM6Ly90ZXN0LnNhbGVzZm9yY2UuY29tLw==`

If we  pass this string data `aHR0cHM6Ly90ZXN0LnNhbGVzZm9yY2UuY29tLw==` based on the util provided by
https://gist.github.com/nxtr/bca4984cd3753261995c421711729629 
displayed actual correct data present in the txt file as "https://test.salesforce.com/".

So how can we upload file .txt into AWS S3 bucket, that actually displays correct data "https://test.salesforce.com/" instead of `aHR0cHM6Ly90ZXN0LnNhbGVzZm9yY2UuY29tLw==`

Can anyone please help.
thanks,

Thanks for reply @sfdcfox
these are my observations 
1) file uploaded successfully, but with above issues, this is the request

```
String url = 'https://' + this.bucketName + '.s3.amazonaws.com/' + this.folderName + '/' + this.fileName;   
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();   
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod('PUT');
        req.setHeader('X-Amz-Content-SHA256',  this.getXAmzContent());
        req.setHeader('X-Amz-Date', this.timestamp);
        req.setHeader('Authorization', this.getPutAuthHeader());
        req.setBody(body);
```

2) Then tried your code,

```
String url = 'https://' + this.bucketName + '.s3.amazonaws.com/' + this.folderName + '/' + this.fileName;   
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();   
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod('PUT');
        req.setHeader('X-Amz-Content-SHA256',  this.getXAmzContent());
        req.setHeader('X-Amz-Date', this.timestamp);
        req.setHeader('Authorization', this.getPutAuthHeader());
        Blob testBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(body);
        if(testBlob.size() > 0) {
        req.setHeader('Content-Length', String.valueOf(testBlob.size()));
        req.setBodyAsBlob(testBlob);
       }
```

getting this error

```
<Code>XAmzContentSHA256Mismatch</Code><Message>The provided 'x-amz-content-sha256' header does not match what was computed.</Message><ClientComputedContentSHA256>
```

What mistake I making ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HttpRequest.setBodyAsBlob. Presumably, you're currently using EncodingUtil.bsae64Encode followed by HttpRequest.setBody, which will result in the encoding that you see. In my [AWS](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/92cf05807ac4becbd21f) code, that part of the code looks like:

```
    if(payload.size() > 0) {
        setHeader('Content-Length', String.valueOf(payload.size()));
        request.setBodyAsBlob(payload);
    }
```

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox, tried your code, but getting header errors for XAmzContentSHA256Mismatch

Comment: @Sunrise487 Then you're calculating it incorrectly. Did you take a look at my code? Also, I'm using v4 of the API, make sure you're not trying to use v2.